# Chrome 32 - Tab opened with chrome extension doesn't render plug-in correctly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi

We have a Chrome extension that can be used to open a page into our website.  From there the user then continues onto the next page which has a custom NPAPI plug-in embedded in it.  This has always worked fine.  However, since the version 32 update the plug-in loads and runs (it's a video conferencing plug-in and is clearly running as the other side can see video) however it doesn't show up on the page.  Examining the DOM everything looks fine.  Grabbing the border and re-sizing the browser will cause the plug-in to suddenly render correctly.  I've tried all manner of javascript/css tricks to try and mimic this behavior as a workaround but nothing works. Tabs opened manually (not using chrome.tabs.create) work fine.
This worked up till 32.
Any ideas around this?

Comment: Have you filed a bug at http://crbug.com? That's the best way to both ensure future versions don't have the same bug, and to find out from people who know the internals if there's a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome 32 is phasing out NPAPI, read the [announcement here.](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html)

There is a deprecation guide that you can read [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation).

It seems like Google wants you to use it's [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/) tech to run native compiled code on user's machines. It is cool stuff...but so far I've found it difficult/more limiting to work with when compared to NPAPI (but there are obvious upsides, security for instance).

You could also build a native app and use [native message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to communicate from extension -> app. Once downside to this is that there is currently no way to bundle a native app into an extension install, so the user will need to download and install your app separately.

Comment: Yeah we're aware NPAPI is on the way out :) I did look at that a bit.  I came away with the impression that native messaging will only work if the app is built using NACL, which because of our needed access to hardware won't work.  Back to the issue though, it's annoying because it does work in most cases, and it is running.  It's just being "hidden" for lack of a better term.  It's simply a rendering issue on the page that's only exhibited when the tab is opened using the extension API.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Native messaging apps do not have to be built with NaCL, they can communicate with chrome extensions using stdin/stdout. There are restrictions on where you place the installed apps and more details on the [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) page of the dev guide. In my testing, this approach actually works pretty well (although it is a pain to setup). Depending on what your app wants to do this could be an option for you.